# How to sum values if I don't have column to group it by

Tags: sql, presto, mode-analytics

I need to sum sales grouped by country, but I have to group them manually because I don't have any other way.
Unfortunately, I don't have the column 'continent', but there are not too many countries on the list so I can do it manually. I can't create any new columns in the table, so I need to do it in a query.

For example:

```
country | sum of sales
Germany    1000
Italy      500
Canada     700
UK         1300
USA        3000
```

I would like to see the total sales for Europe and  North America

```
continent | sum of sales
Europe          2800
North America   3700
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does your countries table have a continent column? How do you handle Turkey and Russia?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, how do I group by manually?

Comment: @jarlh, due sensitive date, I changed the logic behind my query. Honestly, I'm working with some names and I replaced them with countries.

Comment: If you can't add a column to the table, can you add a table, even just a temporary one?

Comment: I can add a column to the table in a way to write for example CASE statement, but can't add it so it stays permanently.

I'm so sorry if I'm bringing confusion, I'm pretty new in all this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to combine `case` expression and `in` predicate, something along this lines:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN country in ('Germany', 'UK') THEN 'Europe'
    WHEN country in ('Canada', 'USA') THEN 'North America'
    END as continent,
    sum("sum of sales")
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: I'm writing my query in PrestoDB and getting the following message:
"java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:26: IN value and list items must be the same type: array(varchar) [Execution ID: 55b867bb-8e4e-483b-a91f-215dcbeb464c]"

Comment: Just a small note: `case` _expression_, `in` _predicate_.

Comment: @Zole72 was not able to reproduce, [this](https://pastebin.com/fDKTVd8S) works just fine for me.